# How to compare two variable values?

Tags: javascript

I am making a password app where you first create a password and save it to a variable. Once the variable has the value, you can enter the password. If the user got it wrong three times, I want to hide the input box and show a message. So far it is working, but it doesn't compare the two variables. Here is my code:

```
<p id='password'></p>

<input type='password' title='enter your password'>
<input type="submit" onclick='passwords__()'>

<button onclick='savePassword()'>
Save Your New Password
</button>

<script>
var times = 0;
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var passwords = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
var buttons2 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

function passwords__() {
    times++;
    if (times === 3) {
        input.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = 'You can\'t enter your password because you have not enter the right one for three times';
    }
    if (input.value === passwords) {
        alert('You\'re loged in');
    }

}
</script>

<script>
function firstCall() {
    buttons.style.display = 'none';
}
firstCall();
</script>

<script>
function savePassword() {
    buttons.style.display = 'block';
    buttons2.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `var passwords = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value` you set `password` to the value when the page is loaded and not when the save password button is loaded.

You should

1. put the `savePassword` function in the same block where you defined the `passwords` variable
2. set the value of `passwords` in the `savePassword` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
var passwords = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

is probably running before the button is pressed, so the value isn't being retrieved when the button is pressed - move this line into your passwords__() function.

Also, use

```
window.onload = function() {
    
}
```

to ensure that the document.getElementsByTagName() is running after the function is fully loaded;

```
window.onload = function() {
    var times = 0;
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
    var buttons2 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
}


function passwords__() {
    times++;
    let passwords = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

    if (times === 3) {
      input.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = 'You can\'t enter your password because you have not enter the right one for three times';
    }

    if (input.value === passwords) {
      alert('You\'re logged in');
    }
 }
```

Side note: You have a typo in alert('You're loged in'); (loged -> logged)

Answer (score 0):

what you were missing

- you were comparing the second input to an empty string because you are running it before the event of clicking

there are some things you can improve here .

- **password disappears after save**
- **times count to 0 when logged in**

```js
var times = 0;
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var pass1;
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
var buttons2 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
function passwords__(){
times++;
pass2 = input.value;
if(times === 3 && pass2 !== pass1){

input.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = 'You can\'t enter your password because you have not enter the right one for three times';
}
console.log(pass1)
if(pass2 == pass1){
alert('You\'re loged in');
times = 0 ;
}

}


function firstCall(){
button.style.display = 'none';
}

firstCall();

function savePassword(){
pass1 = input.value;

input.value = '';

button.style.display = 'block';
buttons2.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<p id='password'>
</p>
<input type='password' title='enter your password'>
<input type="submit" onclick='passwords__()'>
<button onclick='savePassword()'>
Save Your New Password
</button>
```